# How can I make a Raspberry Pi Qt application running on EGLFS invisible/minimized?

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am having trouble getting my application (which uses Qt's EGLFS plugin platform) to be cleared from the screen once it has been 'painted' to.

It is a Qt Quick application with an ApplicationWindow root object in QML, whose visibility can be set to false on startup, without issue.

However, once it has been set to true, setting it to false will cause the last shown frame to persist until the application is either made visible again or explicitly quit.

What options do I have to hide the application, whilst allowing its process to persist?

Comment: I have the exact same question, did you by any chance find an answer to this?